# Advection-Diffusion PDE in C++

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

For a PDE
$
\frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{x}}(S - \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{x}}) + f,$ what would be the simplest `C++` library to use? I assume this needs to be recast as an ODE first, by using finite difference schemes (is it true?). So, for exploratory purposes, without resorting to powerful and more complex tools such as e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.13282.pdf), how one would setup a simple `C++` code that manipulates basic arrays and matrices, and perhaps only uses a call to a third-party ODE solver such as e.g. [this](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/)? I think nothing fancy is required here: some grid-like discretization suffices. Since I haven't touched these things for quite some time, I would like to see an outline of a workflow, if I were to develop the simplest and most basic `C++` solver from scratch.

EDIT: Put another way, for a non-expert in numerical methods but only with a basic background, is it possible to code, as a weekend project, a most basic computation procedure for such an equation? What is the most non-trivial part? The title says `C++` explicitly, because there are packages such as `ReacTran` and `deSolve` in `R` that seem to handle these sorts of questions.

Comment: How would you recast this PDE as an ODE? This puzzles me.

Comment: @llonpilaaja You could do some research on mathematical software eg Maple, Matlab, etc, ask questions about those on SME forums as initial ideas

Comment: @Gribouillis, for example like https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36694/implementing-dirichlet-bc-for-the-advection-diffusion-equation-using-a-second-or?